# Appropriate word and kanji for 'caller'

Tags: nuances, verbs

Skipping the how/why/etc, I have a daikyu that has earned the name 'Windcaller'. I'm familiar with kaze(風) for wind, but I'm a bit perplexed about which verb invokes the best match for the intent of caller in this context.

- yobiyoseru(呼び寄せる) - to call; to summon; to send for; to call together
- maneku(招く) - (1) to invite; to ask; (2) to beckon; to wave someone in; to gesture to; (3) to call in; to send for; to summon; (4) to bring on oneself; to cause; to incur; to lead to; to result in
- manekiyoseru(招き寄せる) - to gesture to come closer; to beckon; to call; to summon
- izanau (誘う) - (いざなう is arch) to invite; to ask; to call (for); (2) to tempt; to lure; to induce;

Or is there something better nuanced? Also not familiar with Japanese grammatical structure on how one would turn whichever verb into a noun.  Would the construction be Kaze no [Caller], Kaze(caller) as one word, or some other construction?

Doumo Arigatou gozaimasu for any help!

Comment: Hmm, guess WWWJDIC's romanji lookup isn't 100% accurate, lesson learned!

Comment: What's "daikyu"? Do you need a word for "windcaller", "stormcaller" used in some fantasy works?

Comment: A long Japanese yumi(archery bow).  Usually used in Kyudo, though I actually use mine for target shooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, one reasonable choice is just transliterate it and call it **ウィンドコーラー**. After all, you want to call your bow "daikyu", not "big bow", because it sounds better to your ears. Pretty much in the same way, if you want a name that sounds cool to the ears of Japanese people, sometimes it's best to leave it untranslated.

But if you do want to give a Japanese name to your bow, read on. The natural and straightforward verb choice would be 呼ぶ (*yobu*, "to call").

- 風を呼ぶ does sound like someone is calling wind, maybe using some magical 
  power.
- 風を呼び寄せる is fine, but unnecessarily lengthy for your purpose.
- 風を招く／風を誘う would make sense as a literary expression, but they're not very common, and they may sound gentle/cute rather than powerful.
- 風を[起こす](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%99) is a plain and common expression which means "cause wind". But it's easily done with a fan. Probably you need a more appealing word for your Windcaller :-)

One way to make a verb into a noun and simulate the English suffix `-er` is to use the i-form (or *ren'yō-kei*) of the verb. (e.g. ピアノを弾く = to play the piano; ピアノ弾き = piano player, pianist) This method does not work with all verbs, but it works with 呼ぶ. Using this method, you'll get one possible translation of Windcaller: **風呼び** (*kaze yobi*). This seems to be actually used in some games and manga (like [this](https://gamy.jp/crystalia/dictionary/cards/3896) and [this](http://games.gaym.jp/iPhone/towerrising/wiki/?%E9%A2%A8%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%AC%9B)). You can also say **風呼びの弓** (*kaze yobi no yumi*, windcalling bow).

Alternatively, you can use [relative clause](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause) and say **風を呼ぶ者** (*kaze wo yobu mono*, if the caller is a person/humanoid), **風を呼ぶ弓** (*kaze wo yobu yumi*, if the caller is a bow), etc.

Comment: Couldn't you drop the の to make it more like a title/compound word, and go with 風呼び弓?

Comment: @Darcinon It's possible, but uncommon. According to Google, 竜殺しの剣 is 100 times more common than 竜殺し剣 (and ドラゴンスレイヤー is 10 times more common than 竜殺しの剣).

Comment: @Darcinon It'd sound like a certain classification of bows rather than a proper name to my ear.

Comment: 風呼び definitely seems like a good fit, and implying somewhat of a proper name connotation over 風呼びの弓.  As for why kanji over katakana(and daikyu over 'big bow'), its for a more culturally correct feel as my archery is with the SCA(Society for Creative Anachronism) and I try to be respectful of the real deal while being pretend Japanese :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @naruto for a great answer, but I'll also offer up [召喚]{しょう・かん} in place of 呼び.  召喚 means "summon", and I've seen it in video games when referring to summoners/summonees(?).

So you might name it something like `風召喚弓` (though not sure if the 風 would be better as かぜ or ふう).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something with 者{もの}, like 風{かぜ}を呼{よ}び寄{よ}せる者｛もの｝(He who calls forth wind) or 風{かぜ}を操{あやつ}る者{もの} (He who controls wind).

Judging by the original English name, it looks very 中二病 to me, so I assume these terms would fit well.

Or you can just call yourself 風{かぜ}の妖精{ようせい} (wind fairy)!